Почему не работают импорты VK SDK?
Не могу понять почему не работает импорт VKSdk, VKAccessToken, VKError, VKParameters и так далее что связано с vk sdk, хотя зависимость версии 4.1.0 установилась.
"Unresolved reference 'VKSdk', 'VKAccessToken', 'VKError'"
MainActivity.kt:
    import android.content.Intent
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.util.Log
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    import com.vk.sdk.VKSdk
    import com.vk.sdk.api.VKAccessToken
    import com.vk.sdk.api.VKError
    import com.vk.sdk.api.VKParameters
    import com.vk.sdk.api.VKRequest
    import com.vk.sdk.api.VKResponse
    import com.vk.sdk.api.model.VKPost
    import com.vk.sdk.api.model.VKWallPost
    import com.vk.sdk.api.VKRequest.VKRequestListener
    import com.vk.sdk.util.VKUtil
    import com.vk.sdk.api.VKScope

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val posts = mutableListOf<Post>()
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var postsAdapter: PostsAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Инициализация VK SDK
        VKSdk.initialize(applicationContext)

        // Инициализируем RecyclerView для отображения постов
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
        postsAdapter = PostsAdapter(posts)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView.adapter = postsAdapter

        // Запрашиваем права на доступ к стене
        VKSdk.login(this, VKScope.WALL)
    }

settings.gradle:
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven { url = uri("https://maven.vk.com") }
    }
}

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url = uri("https://maven.vk.com") }
    }
}

build.gradle:
dependencies {

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
    implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.graphics)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling.preview)
    implementation(libs.androidx.material3)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
    androidTestImplementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.junit4)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.manifest)
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1")
    implementation ("com.vk:android-sdk-core:4.1.0")
    implementation ("com.vk:android-sdk-api:4.1.0")
}


Скорее всего вы взяли пример для какой-то из старых версий библиотек, а в актуальной этих классов уже нет. Изучайте доки на офф. сайте
